# How to read URL in a faster way than file_get_content?

Tags: php

I need to run about 100 PHP pages, a little complicated.

I can run them using cronjob, but I prefer through a single PHP page.

What I've done with my home webserver so far: (End time 30-60 seconds)

```
<?php
file_get_contents("http://website.com&page1");
file_get_contents("http://website.com&page2");
file_get_contents("http://website.com&page3");
file_get_contents("http://website.com&page4");
file_get_contents("http://website.com&page5");
file_get_contents("http://website.com&page6");
file_get_contents("http://website.com&page7");
file_get_contents("http://website.com&page8");
file_get_contents("http://website.com&page9");
file_get_contents("http://website.com&page10");
Until number 100...
```

But I try now on my external webserver and the code is delayed for at least 5 minutes, which also extend the time in php.ini not helping.

Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this, its dirty but it works

```
 <?php
set_time_limit(0);
for ($x = 0; $x <= 100; $x++) {
file_get_contents("http://website.com&page".$x);
}
?>
```

This will let the script run forever if need be, this is not a great way to do things because the script could run forever and fill up your server mem.

For your use case though it will work

Comment: Thanks, working on my home webserver faster. The VPS webserver continues to load slowly the 100 pages, I think because the ram only 1gb (aws free)

Comment: yeah that will be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using a shell script :

```
#!/bin/sh

for a in `seq 100`
do
   wget -O/dev/null -q "http://website.com?page$a"
done
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((a=1;a<=100;a++)); 
do
   wget -O/dev/null -q "http://website.com?page$a"
done
```

Comment: Thanks! I will immediately check, but if there is also a way with PHP I would love to know

Comment: @phong You could do use PHP but run it in CLI.

Comment: @phong I checked the 2 sh, it did not work. Need to add time? Because the pages in general are loaded up to 10 seconds. from https://wget.alanreed.org/ it works, just for the test of single page